# What is the height of different layers of the atmosphere?

Tags: atmospheric-science

I have a confusion regarding the height of different layers of [atmosphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Earth). I have searched for this in some books but the information varies.

Comment: See also [Earthscience.SE] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

The information varies because there is no set value and there *can't* be a set value.

For instance, the transition between troposphere and stratosphere, called the [tropopause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropopause), is defined as the region of the atmosphere around 10 km that features a (roughly) constant temperature (see red line on the right of the image below):

[image]
([source](http://sriutami88.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/the-stratosphere/))

Due to changes in the weather itself, the height of the tropopause is actually variable across the latitude (marked by the red line)

[image]

([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropopause))

Similar variable conditions exist for the [stratopause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratopause) and [mesopause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesopause). Thus, you will not find any set values, only approximate ranges.